# codeigniter database cache doesn't work

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, caching, database-caching

I just want to know because I have an issue with codeigniter database caching.

I tried to enable the cache thru the database.php file

```
$db['default']['cache_on'] = TRUE;
$db['default']['cachedir'] = "application/cache";
```

The thing is, it successfully creates the cache, I can also delete it using $this->db->cache_delete()

There's also no error. But the problem is I can't retrieve the data from the cache.

What do you guys think is the problem.. I've been looking the internet but no luck.

Comment: can I see, how you are trying to get cache data?

Comment: can you give me a hint how should I retrieve the cache data? I have no access right now on my development PC.

Comment: According to the user guide (http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/database/caching.html), cache retrieval should be automatic. Can you please post your code (or relevant snippets)?

Comment: Yes, that's what I read also that no need to retrieve, it does automatically. I tried $this->cache->get('my_cached_item'); but no luck so after reading the documentation again for query caching, I remove it because it says that codeigniter does it automatically. So to summarize what I did is I just configured the database.php, and that should work. But unfortunately I cant retrieve the data..

Comment: $db['default']['cache_on'] = TRUE;
$db['default']['cachedir'] = "application/cache";

this is what I only did. no addtional codes just the setup

Comment: Check if maybe the cache directory is not writable for your script.